# How to refer to a list?

Tags: prepositions, lists

I have a list containing some information and I need to refer to that list. Is a sentence "From the list above ... " ok? Example:

- item 1
- item 2
- item 3

From the list above is obvious there is a variety of items.

Comment: That part is fine, but the rest is ungrammatical, and the sentence as a whole is sort of pointless. As you say, it is obvious that there are items in the list, so it is a waste of the reader's time to tell them it is obvious there are items in the list. You can just scrap the sentence altogether.

Comment: That was just an example, the list actually contains other information, I just simplified it. Sorry for misunderstanding, next time I'll present the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grammar is O.K. because the implied prepositional phrase is unambiguous:

"Please make a selection from the list *{above this sentence.}*  "